# How would you sync a real life accelerometer with an accelerometer in a simulation program

Tags: gyroscope, accelerometer, simulator

How would you sync a real life accelerometer with an accelerometer in a simulation program.
In this case I am using MuJoCo for simulation and a Gy-521 is my physical, real life accelerometer.

Comment: So, it gives the standard units for measuring acceleration? Is that what you're getting at? "Acceleration is quantified in the SI unit metres per second per second"

Comment: I didn't get far in science class. I'm looking it up. Acceleration is change in velocity. Okay. Well, I was just using miles per hour to frame my problem with something known that has a know metric. You won't say if the accelerometer measures meter per second squared? I don't understand the metric. Not really. What is going relative to a meter per second squared? Because the measurements drop off. If it measures acceleration just tell me it measures acceleration. Okay, what's the next riddle?

Comment: " it could be a change in frequency, or a change in voltage, or it could be a change in binary value" This is confusing me. I want to sync up the virtual accelerometer and the physical one.

Comment: I deleted most after `I am using MuJoCo`.

Comment: https://roboti.us/book/haptix.html

Comment: Thank you. The answer always comes from the docs or someone showing me the docs. 
According to MuJoCo it's 'linear acceleration'. Meters per second squared. I guess I'll look at the Gy-521 docs and think about what test I can do to check the gap between action and sensor.

Comment: are you certain that you want to *sync* a real accelerometer with sim accelerometer? ... it is unclear what you mean by that ... maybe all you want is to feed the data from a real accelerometer into the simulation

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very open ended as "syncing" is not clearly defined. I'm going to answer as best i can interpret your intent.

An accelerometer is a sensor which measures acceleration in the world. A simulated sensor in the simulation should likewise be measuring acceleration in the simulated world.

Do you that end to cause the simulated sensor to provide the same readings you should take the real sensors readings. Estimate the motions of the real system which caused those accelerations. Then send those motions to the simulator to be executed. And if you've estimated the motion accurately and modeled the system will enough in the simulation the accelerometers will be in sync, aka giving the same readings.